# Joint density of normal random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

> Let $Z=X+Y$ where $X$~$N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $Y$~$N(0,1)$ are
>   independents. Find the joint density of Z and X.

This is the first time I see something like that, look what I did below:

I know that $Z=X+Y$~$N(\mu,\sigma^2+1)$, but it does not help a lot, so I developed through Jacobian

$Z=X+Y$ and $W=X$, this I have that Jacobian $J=-1\Rightarrow |J|^{-1}=1$, and solving that equations $X=W$ and $Y=Z-W$, then

$$f_{x,y}(x,y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(x-\mu)^2}*\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^2}$$
$$f_{x,y}(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}[(x-\mu)^2+\sigma^2y^2]}=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}[x^2-2\mu x+\mu^2+\sigma^2y^2]}$$
replacing $X$ and $Y$
$$f_{z,w}(z,w)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}[w^2-2\mu w+\mu^2+\sigma^2(z-w)^2]}=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}[w^2-2\mu w+\mu^2+\sigma^2(z^2-2zw+w^2)]}$$

Now I'm stuck, I can not simplify anything and do not even know you have to do something.

Comment: You ask to find the joint density of Z and X and not of X and Y, right?

Comment: @pidosaurus Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $Z\sim N(\mu,1+\sigma^2)$ and $X\sim(\mu,\sigma^2)$ are **jointly** normal, it suffices to know their covariance.

$$
E[ZX]-E[Z]E[X] = E[(X+Y)X] - \mu^2 = E[X^2] + E[XY] - \mu^2 = (\sigma^2 + \mu^2) + 0 - \mu^2 = \sigma^2
$$

Thus $(Z,X)$ is a bivariate normal with mean
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}
\mu\\
\mu
\end{array}\right)
$$ and covariance matrix
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\sigma^2+1 & \sigma^2\\
\sigma^2 & \sigma^2
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: I did not learn about covariance matrix, there is no way to get it through what I did?

Comment: If you aren't familiar with bivariate normals, then your answer should just be $(Z,X)$ has the joint density given by [last math line in your question]. It does not simplify further.

Comment: Can you help me here [Conditional](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1318415/conditional-probability-ratio-of-bivariate-normal-and-normal)?